# PHP trying to change post_max_size and upload_max_filesize

Tags: php, macos, xampp, php-ini

I am using XAMPP on Mac and I am trying to locate my php.ini file and I ran the phpinfo() function and found the path to php.ini file and when I open it the post_max_size and upload_max_filesize have different values then phpinfo, I changed the values and restarted my server and the changes did not take effect. How do I find out where the php.ini file is?

Comment: Whatever `phpinfo()` says your INI file is, that's what it is.  Are you sure you're not including other INI files?

Comment: Just to make sure you're looking at the correct spot in the `phpinfo()` output, could you post the output of `var_dump(php_ini_loaded_file());`?